# What should we do about [zero-gravity]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tagging

I'm wondering what we should do with [zero-gravity](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zero-gravity) - as we all know, [zero gravity does not exist](http://www.nasa.gov/centers/glenn/shuttlestation/station/microgex.html) - the correct term is [microgravity](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microgravity), which we already have a tag for. Furthermore, all the [zero-gravity](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zero-gravity) questions could be retagged [microgravity](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microgravity), with no adverse side affects.

What should we do about this 'misleading' tag?

Comment: i think its because non technicals get confused and view microgravity as being within the range of an object but gravity is weak, so then use no gravity for reasons where they are in deep space with no bodies but their own ship for light years either way

Comment: [tag:zero-gravity] has been merged into [tag:microgravity].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make [microgravity](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microgravity) and [zero-gravity](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zero-gravity) synonyms.

Comment: Synonym request created on microgravity pointing to zero gravity. Hope I did it right!

Comment: @Undo - please ping those who have 1250+ rep points to vote.

Comment: @Undo - think it should be the other way round if you consider [tag:microgravity] to be more correct.

Comment: I think I did it right from my understanding of [this page](http://space.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms?tab=newest&filter=all). In case you can't tell, this is the first time I've ever used this privilege anywhere,

Comment: @Undo - thanks. I can see it now.

Answer (score 0):

An analogy.

Also vacuum does not exist. More or less gas molecules exist everywhere, sometimes only a single atom in a $m^3$ or so. Beside that, virtual particles and quantum fields might be also there (more phylosophical question if we could consider these as existing matter).

However, the practical meaning of vacuum is the lack of a practically observable atmosphere. It would be hilarious to call vacuum as, for example, "micro-pressure environment".

On this reason, I believe that "micro-gravity" is not an useful terminology and using it instead "weightlessness" or "gravity-less environment" is no good.

I disagree the killing of the tag.

Comment: I agree that micro-gravity is a poor term. Good old free fall is best. Something in orbit around a neutron star is affected by enormous gravity, it's crazy to call it micro-gravity. But it's in free fall.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I'd second free-fall as an appropriate tag.